# Plotting grouped data in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have some data that looks like this:

```
    A   B
0   0.575759    0.284667
1   0.870056    0.373226
2   0.912662    0.198353
3   0.206561    0.708886
4   0.551092    0.522910
5   0.183962    0.478480
6   0.934851    0.117349
7   0.968205    0.976065
8   0.969461    0.369844
9   0.148844    0.527356
10  0.728317    0.421314
11  0.882704    0.744687
12  0.160463    0.259014
13  0.288964    0.196615
14  0.131641    0.026985
15  0.746087    0.526483
16  0.735774    0.956830
17  0.584424    0.660203
18  0.329159    0.457387
19  0.387253    0.871913
```

I would like to do the following:

1. Group by column A based on some size (say 0.2), and then average the corresponding B values per A group.
2. Plot the resulting means as a function of the group value. So it would look like a histogram/bar plot with ticks at the (0, 0.2, 0.4, 0.6, ...) for a grouping of size 0.2, and each bin value would be the mean from 1).

Is there a clean way to do this?

Comment: Look at `pd.cut`.

Comment: But how would I plot this?